# Spring mock mvc test return 404 @withmockuser

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, spring-security

When i don't use @WithMockUser return status 401 but when i use @WithMockUser return status code 404

**My Contoller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/stocks")
@Api(tags = "stocks")
@Slf4j
public class StockResource {

  @GetMapping("/test/test")
  @Secured("SYS_ADMIN")
  public @ResponseBody String getTest() {
      return "hello";
  }}
```

**My Test**

```
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration
class RonadTestApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(authorities = {"SYS_ADMIN"})
    void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/api/stocks/test/test")
                .contentType("application/json"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

and my output when i dont use **@WithMockUser**

```
Status expected:<200> but was:<401>
Expected :200
Actual   :401
```

and my output when i use **@WithMockUser**

```
Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to test the role-based access, but in the annotation you are  specifiying an authority.  Since *@Secured()* annotation specifies a role that should be granted access, not an authority (more on that here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security).
Try using *@WithMockuser(**roles** = "SYS_ADMIN")*  instead

```
 @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = {"SYS_ADMIN"})   //<===== here
    void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/api/stocks/test/test")
                .contentType("application/json"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```